# Set static permissions on shared folders

Tags: linux, files, permissions, windows, acl

I have a folder I use for Steam games, and it's shared between Linux and Windows systems. I have this problem that if Windows system has accessed the folder it changes the permissions, locking out Linux system from running said games.

Obviously when you access Steam games from a folder, games need to be able to update when they become available which means that directory needs to have Read-Write permissions to do so otherwise it'll return `NO ERROR` or in this case `CONTENT FILE LOCKED` which means the game cannot run because permissions have been changed by Windows.

I need a way where I can have this shared Steam games folder where it tells Windows to leave the permissions alone to stop overwriting the permissions that already exist. Is there some kind of hidden flag or file I can apply to folder directories.

Probably might be easier if I was using SAMBA, but I am not using that. The drive directory is Ext4, and Windows is able to read and execute games thanks to DOKAN Library which allows Windows to see, read and write to Ext2/3/4 drives. It's not perfect and does like to BSOD sometimes for reading some files because the DOKAN Library hooks itself on to `exfat.sys` to make read-write-execute possible on Ext2/3/4 drives from Windows.

Comment: Could use a login script that corrects the permissions when you start under Linux.

Comment: I could do that, but that won't cut it. Even if I do change the permissions back to the correct ones, it still thinks its locked.